# Calculate $\int_{C(1)}(z-a)^{-n}(z-b)^{-n}dz$ where $|a|<|b|<1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have a problem with calculating this integral:
$$\int_{C(1)}(z-a)^{-n}(z-b)^{-n}dz$$ where $|a|<|b|<1$. Both $a$ and $b$ are inside C(1) so I though it might be convenient to use Cauchy theorem. Is it right aproach? I tried to factorize it to make it work with theorem and came up with nothing usefull. Will be very gratefull for sugestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did a regular complex analysis course, but I think this works:

$$ \frac{1}{z-a}\frac{1}{z-b} = \frac{1}{a-b}\bigg( \frac{1}{z-a}- \frac{1}{z-b} \bigg)$$
$$ \bigg(\frac{1}{z-a}\frac{1}{z-b}\bigg)^n = \frac{1}{(a-b)^n}\bigg( \frac{1}{z-a}- \frac{1}{z-b} \bigg)^n = \frac{1}{(a-b)^n}\bigg( \frac{-n}{(z-a)^{n-1}}\frac{1}{z-b} +\cdots +  \frac{n}{z-a}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(z-b)^{n-1}}\bigg)
$$
Therefore, the integral is $$ \frac{2\pi i}{(a-b)^n}\bigg(\frac{-n}{(b-a)^{n-1}}+\frac{n}{(b-a)^{n-1}}\bigg) = 0$$
Don't know if that is true. Please tell me to delete this post if I got the answer wrong.

Comment: $\bigg( \frac{1}{z-a}- \frac{1}{z-b} \bigg)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k}\frac{1}{(z-a)^{n-k}}\frac{1}{(z-b)^{k}}$ From what I see you didn't take into account $k=0$ and I am apparently missing something but I don't see how it turns out to be $\frac{2\pi i}{(a-b)^n}\bigg(\frac{-n}{(b-a)^{n-1}}+\frac{n}{(b-a)^{n-1}}\bigg)$

Comment: @vanHohenheim Have you learnt Cauchy residue theorem yet? I believe that I am using it

Comment: Now I see it, thanks!

Comment: @vanHohenheim You are welcome! I know I skipped too much details